# Does Scala slick have timeout setting?

Tags: scala, timeout, slick

I noticed in Play! there are couple of settings I can put in application.conf to specify the connection timeout. Since Play! directly leverages Scala slick, I thought there should be similar settings in Scala slick as well, however I cannot find any reference for it so far. I would be surprised if it is unavailable yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you configure the connection pool with the Play settings. If you use Slick with a connection pool (`Database.fromDataSource`) you can configure the timeout in the connection pool. It's nothing Slick specific.