# Scala Playframework Slick: how to pass PostgreSQL params?

Tags: postgresql, playframework, slick

This [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html) says that I can use *idle_in_transaction_session_timeout* config param, but I don't know how to pass it to postgresql. Currently I'm using this config in application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost..."
slick.dbs.default.db.user="..."
slick.dbs.default.db.password="..."
```

I've tried like this (doesn't work):

```
slick.dbs.default.db.log_min_duration_statement = 100
slick.dbs.default.db.idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=1
slick.dbs.default.db.properties = {
  idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=1
  log_min_duration_statement = 100
}
```

I'm using playframework 2.6.11, slick 3.2.1, postgresql 9.4
My question how can I set query execution timeout to postgresql while using playframework?

Comment: did you check this link - http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/database.html

Comment: @AvinashAnand just checked it out. Couldn't find useful info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803170/does-scala-slick-have-timeout-setting says I've to configure it with connection pool. But I don't use *fromDataSource* and also don't use HikariCP.

Comment: Just realized that parameter *idle_in_transaction_session_timeout* was introduced in postgresql 9.6, but I'm using 9.4. Try to find solution if it's reason.